# Regular Expression Matching With Underscores

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python's re package (yes I am aware that regular expressions are more general, but who knows, there may be other packages) to read some data which includes inequalities with variable names after which come +, -, >, < or =. (It's a system of inequalities.) I need to filter out the variable names.

Up until now, I used

```
var_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z|A-Z]+\d*\.?')
```

which is somewhat 'hacky' as it isn't too general. I didn't mind but came across a problem with weird names as below.

My next go was

```
var_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z|A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*')
```

which should, after at least one initial letter, match just about everything that occurs except for +,-, >, < and =. This works nice with variable names like 'x23' oder 'C2000001.' but not with 'x_w_3_dummy_1'. I would have thought it might still be because of the underscore but it seems to work just fine with the variable 'x_b_1_0_0'.

Does anybody have an idea of what might cause and, more importantly, how to fix it?

As an aside, I also tried

```
var_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z|A-Z]+[^+^-^>^<^=]*')
```

but to no avail either.

Comment: Your variable name can also start with `|`; is that correct? You also do not want to include `.` in variable names, do you?

Comment: Is `.` permissible in your variable names?

Comment: Re: `[^+^-^>^<^=]`  You only need the `^` at the start for a negative character set - I think what you meant was `[^+-><=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern should work just fine for your example, but correcting your pattern a little to actually match your intention:

```
r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
```

This matches *1* initial letter (lower or uppcase), followed by 0 or more letters, digits and underscores. Your version had a redundant `+`, and included `|` in what was allowed for the first character, and `.` for the rest of the name.

A demonstration to show this matches all your samples:

```
>>> import re
>>> names = ('x23', 'C2000001', 'x_w_3_dummy_1', 'x_b_1_0_0')
>>> var_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*')
>>> for name in names:
...     print var_pattern.search(name).group()
... 
x23
C2000001
x_w_3_dummy_1
x_b_1_0_0
```

The pattern does not match any `+`, `-`, `>`, `<` or `=` characters that might follow the variable name:

```
>>> var_pattern.findall('x23<10\nC2000001=24\nx_w_3_dummy_1+15\nx_b_1_0_0-5')
['x23', 'C2000001', 'x_w_3_dummy_1', 'x_b_1_0_0']
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed how I am just stupid there... Sorry for stealing your time and thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered, apart from why your original expression didn't work with your underscores.  If you have the pattern

```
r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'
```

then because of the dot it's actually equivalent to

```
r'[a-zA-Z].*'
```

so contrary to what you thought, this does match both your "x_w_3_dummy_1" *and* your "x_b_1_0_0".  The problem is that because of the dot it will also match your subsequent delimiter, like your +,-, >, < and = as well as anything after it.